# PHP: how to do array_search with 40% Partial Matching

Tags: php

i am using php partial matching. but problem is this there is a huge list of matching available every time. we want to limit it. it only shows the partial match when it matches 40 % *(means 4 characters out of 10)*.

Comment: Where is your tried code?

Comment: You need to give us more information in order to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function fuzzyMatch ($source, $term, $percentRequired){
    $matches = array_filter($source, function($test) use ($term, $percentRequired){
           $matchPer = null;
           similar_text($term, $test, $matchPer);
           return $matchPer >= $percentRequired;
    });
    return $matches;
}
```

This will take an array or terms, the term you want to match it against and the % required for a match and return an array the matching values.